# Share data between tests

Tags: global-variables, automated-tests, qtp

I know we can share parameters between actions in the same test by putting them in Global data table.

Is there a way to share data / parameters between tests in QTP? SO, If I run a batch of tests, and all the tests use a parameter, I want to change the value in one location and not in Global data table of each test.

Comment: how do you run the batch of tests?.. from qc or you use a separate driver script to run the tests..?

Answer (score 0):

You should use XML files for this.
You should first load your XML parameter file : 
You need to declare environement variables in your test this way :

```
   Environment.LoadfromFile "path\params.xml"
```

decalre the variable in your script

```
 user=Environment.Value("username")
```

then use the variable this way in your test

```
   JavaDialog("LoginWin").JavaEdit("JTextField").Set user
```

Then you need to decalre he variable in your xml file :

```
    <Variable>
    <Name>username</Name>
    <Value>admin</Value>
</Variable>
```